# Concourse Worker "file not found"

Tags: concourse

Currently when running concourse-workers with docker-compose.

When you shutdown the stack for restart or upgrade, the worker becomes to be in a broken, undefined state.

This leads to a lot of different issues like "file not found" when running a task /job in concourse or during a resource trigger job / task is stalled / stuck in the "preparing build" state, not doing anything.

Is there a way to workaround/solve it?

Comment: Removed tags from title; grammar.

Answer (score 0):

We had a similar problem recently.  Without seeing your configuration, this is just a shot in the dark, but we solved it by adding the ssh-port of the web-container to the TSA_HOST config for the worker in `docker-compose.yml`.  (Change in last line below):

```
worker:
  build: concourse-worker
  privileged: true
  links:
    - web
  environment:
    CONCOURSE_TSA_HOST: web:2222
```

Answer (score 0):

It sounds like similar to the issue described [here](https://github.com/concourse/concourse/issues/1854), basically ATC tries to register the same worker name as before the upgrade, but seems like the worker name has changed. So you can do a `fly workers` to get the stalled worker name, `concourse retire-worker` to retire it and register with the new worker using `concourse land-worker`.

A not so pretty way to temporarily solve this is recreate the worker by run the docker-compose again, wait a bit since the new worker needs to register itself with ATC.